# How to show tooltip only for show x values in react charts

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have a line chart where I am displaying only four values but my datasets are larger and as you can the dot on line is shown for all datasets. Is there a way to show only the circle pointer only for x values that are displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the scriptable options for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      radius: (ctx) => {
        let radius = 0;
        ctx.chart.scales.x.ticks.forEach((tick) => {
          if (tick.value === ctx.dataIndex) {
            radius = 5;
          }
        })
        return radius;
      }
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/JjNGVpY